# ionic cordova keyboard pushing ion-footer-bar off screen

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, cordova-plugins

I am writing an app using ionic framework, and have a keyboard issue.  See following screen shot:

**this is the chatting page**, everything goes fine

[image]

then i tap the input bar:

[image]
[image]

could see the keyboard push the footer input bar out of screen.

I use ionic 1.0.0-rc.5, and use `keyboard-attach`  on the `ion-footer-bar`. This problem appears in the ios, i haven't tested android.

Have been struggling for a while, how could i fix it, thanks a lot for help!

**Update:** this view is inside a tab view, and i use `tabs-item-hide` to hide the tab bar. Maybe I should separate it from tabs so the `ion-footer-bar` become the only footer in this page?

**Update:**
I separate the chatting view from tabs view, bug still exists :-(

Answer (score 3):

I delete `keyboard-attach`, then it works.

Following the doc http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/keyboardAttach/ not work, so wierd.

Will updates here if any further bugs or better solutions.

Comment: I've seen this issue in the Ionic View app for iOS, I haven't actually installed to test on an iOS device. I'm currently testing the solution mentioned on the doc page here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/keyboard/      to use the cordova plugin,      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true)

Answer (score 0):

A note for anyone who might enter in the future, keyboard attach did not work in android while using 'cordova-admob-pro' plugin. hiding ads made it work.